# When to use "some" instead of "a"

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-article, determiners

> You were just having **some** dream.

and

> You were just having **a** dream.

Are both correct? What is the difference, if any?

Comment: Is this sentence from somewhere specific, or is it just an example you came up with for the purposes of the question?

Comment: @KenB: It is from the movie *Scott Pilgrim vs. the World* in Minute 10:20.

Comment: *Some* in your first example is a contraction of *some of* something. He was therefore having *some* or *part* of a dream. Having *a dream* refers to the *whole* dream, and not just part or some of it. *You were having some dream!* Changes the meaning to something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, both are correct.

In your first example [*some*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/some?q=some) is being used in an informal way.

There are two plausible interpretations for *some*.

The first possibility is that *some* means the dream is remarkable in some way (meaning 6 in the above link). It takes the place of *a* and adds this extra meaning to the sentence.

So

> You were just having some dream!

Is pretty much the same as saying

> You were just having a remarkable dream!

When you use *some* in this way, you must put emphasis on it.

Another example could be:

> That is an apple.

vs

> That is some apple!

Where the apple could for example be tastier than normal.

*Some*, used in this way, indicates that some attribute of the thing is surprisingly different to normal.

The other possibility is that *some* means *a* but in a dismissive way (meaning 2. in the link I provide).

So

> You were just having some dream.

Could be interpreted as

> You were just having a dream, don't worry about it.

or

> You were just having a dream, it is of no importance.

Another example would be:

> A- Who is that on stage?
>
> B- Oh, just some roadie.

Because *B* doesn't think the roadie is of interest.

Comment: Bear in mind please the OP's question does *not* include an exclamation mark ! therefore your first instance interpretation *may not* be correct.

Comment: @spiceyokooko good point. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

**A** would normally be used in this sense because there was only one dream. **Some** would normally be used when there is an indeterminate amount, e.g. "You were just eating **some** food."

Answer (score 0):

'Some' is used when the quantity of the object in question is either not countable, is unknown, or is not important. So you should say *some sugar*, *some coffee*, but not *some dream*, because *dream* is singular and therefore countable.  However, you can say *some dreams* to indicate more than one dream, but where the exact number of dreams is not significant.