# Difference between "some" and "any"

Tags: difference, determiners, uncountable-nouns, some-vs-any

Can anybody please tell me what the difference between ***some*** and ***any*** is?

Here are two examples:

> 1. Can you please give ***any*** advice on that?
> 2. Can you please give ***some*** advice on that?

Comment: Use **some** when you’re talking about something that is specific and use **any** when you’re talking about something that is not specific. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/learn-the-difference-between-some-and-any-in-less-than-a-minute/

Comment: The use of *any* in that sentence may suggest that the person addressed has given no satisfactory advice so far, but other than that there's no productive difference.

Comment: @Raj33: "Any horse is a quadruped": that is pretty far from specific, yet it's a valid usage. Don't forget that *any* can mean *all*, which is decidedly non-specific.

Comment: related [When to use “some” instead of “a”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280/when-to-use-some-instead-of-a) and [Usage of “any” or “some” in “Would you like … wine?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113090/usage-of-any-or-some-in-would-you-like-wine) and [Using of Some and any](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80217/using-of-some-and-any)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me **any** advice on this? [Idea: Is advice even possible here?]

Can you give me some advice on this? [Idea: Just give me some advice, there is advice that can be given]

Answer (score 0):

**any** refers to an amount, no matter how little of it there may be:

> Is there any salt left?
>   --Yes, but there is only the tiniest pinch.

or to a set that is not the null set:

> Was *any person in the audience* wearing a baseball cap?
>   --Yes, there was a guy wearing a baseball cap.

**some** refers to an indefinite  number:

> Were people in the audience wearing baseball hats?
>   --Yes, some people were wearing baseball hats.
>   Were there many?
>   --Well, more than a few to be sure.

or to an indefinite amount:

> I would like to try some of your soup, but just a little, please.